# Regex operation to modify a string

Tags: python, regex

At the moment I have a string similar to:

```
mytime = '143456.45674'
```

That string is giving time in :

```
%HH%MM:%SS . something else
```

I am only interested in `HH:MM:SS` format so I could do:

```
mynewTime = mytime[0:2]+":"+mytime[2:4]+":"+mytime[4:6]
'14:34:56'
```

It is a bit ugly and I was wondering if there was a more elegant/efficient way of doing it. Regex perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're looking for a combination of `strptime` and `strftime`:

```
import datetime

mytime = '143456.45674'

ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(mytime, '%H%M%S.%f')
print ts.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

# 14:34:56
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex version for fun :)

```
re.sub(r"(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.\d+", r"\1:\2:\3", mytime)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in regex

```
>>> import re
>>> val=re.sub(r"\..*$", "", "143456.45674")
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=\d)(?=(\d{2})+$)", ":", val )
'14:34:56'
```